# Outcome difference: using list & for-loop vs. single parameter input

Tags: for-loop

This is my first question, so please let me know if I'm not giving enough details or asking a question that is not relevant on this platform!

I want to compute the same formula over a grid running from 0 to 4.0209, therefore I'm using a for-loop with an defined array using `numpy`.

To be certain that the for-loop is right, I've computed a selection of values by just using specific values for the radius an input in the formula. 
Now, the outcomes with the same input of the radius is just slightly different. Do I interpret my grid wrongly? Or is there an error in my script? 
It probably is something pretty straightforward, but maybe some of you can find a minute to help me out.

Here I use a selection of values for my radius parameter.
[image]

Here I use a for-loop to compute over a distance
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here are the differences in the outcomes:

Outcomes computed with for-loop:

9.443,086753902220000000

1.935,510475232510000000

57,174050755727700000

1,688894026484580000

0,020682674424032700

Outcomes computed with selected radii:

9.444,748178731630000000

1.938,918526458330000000

57,476599453309800000

1,703815523775800000

0,020957378277984600